# Magento 2 restrict run composer update during setup upgrade

Tags: composer, magento242

I have run `setup:upgrade` and Magento has run the `composer update` command automatically.

Can we restrict this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```

It will keep generated folder without recreating it and hence the dependencies which update during this will be skipped.